# Magento2: I need to get order Purchase Order Date and Purchased From fields in observer

Tags: magento2, order-collection

I need to get order **Purchase Order Date** and **Purchased From fields** in the **observer**.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Abc\Mkt\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface {
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $date;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date, \Abc\Mkt\Model\Orderapi $orderData)
   { 
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
      $this->date = $date;
      $this->orderData = $orderData;
   }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $enable=$this->scopeConfig->getValue('abc_mkt/orderconfig/mkt_order_integration', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        if($enable){ 
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $status = 0;
            $name='';
            $data['Email'] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
            $data['FirstName'] = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
            $data['LastName'] = $order->getCustomerLastName();
            $response= $this->orderData->orderData($data,$status,$name);  
            $res= json_decode($response, true); 
            if($res['success']==1){ 

                $status = 1;
                $oname= $orderobjectname;

                $tdiscount = explode('-', $order["base_discount_amount"]);
                $couponApplied = $order->getCouponCode();                   
                $odata['orderId']= $order->getIncrementId();
                $odata['emailAddress'] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
                $odata['totalOrderAmount'] = $order->getGrandTotal();
                $odata['shippingCostInOrder'] =$order["shipping_amount"];
                $odata['totalQuantity'] = $order["total_qty_ordered"];
                $purchasedOrderDate = $order->getCreatedAt();
                $odata['purchaseOrderDate'] = $purchasedOrderDate;

                $billingObj = $order->getBillingAddress();
                $billStreet = $billingObj->getStreet();
                if(isset($billStreet[1])){ $billStreetComplete =  $billStreet[0].' '.$billStreet[1]; } else { $billStreetComplete = $billStreet[0]; }
                $odata['billingDetails'] =  trim($billingObj->getCompany()).','.$billStreetComplete.','.$billingObj->getRegion().','.$billingObj->getCity().','.$billingObj->getPostcode().';'.'T: '.$billingObj->getTelephone();

                $shippingObj = $order->getShippingAddress();
                if(!empty($shippingObj)){
                    $shipStreet = $shippingObj->getStreet();
                    if(isset($shipStreet[1])){ $shipStreetComplete =  $shipStreet[0].' '.$shipStreet[1]; } else { $shipStreetComplete = $shipStreet[0]; }
                    $odata['shippingDetails'] = trim($shippingObj->getCompany()).','.$shipStreetComplete.','.$shippingObj->getRegion().','.$shippingObj->getCity().','.$shippingObj->getPostcode().';'.'T: '.$shippingObj->getTelephone();
                }

                $odata['couponApplied'] = $couponApplied ;
                if($order["tax"]){
                            $odata['taxInOrder'] =$order["tax"] ;
                } else {
                    $odata['taxInOrder'] =0.00 ;
                }
                if($order->getBaseDiscountAmount()){
                    $tdiscount = explode('-', $order->getBaseDiscountAmount());
                    if($tdiscount){
                        $odata['totalOrderDiscount'] = $tdiscount[1];
                    }else{
                        $odata['totalOrderDiscount'] = 0.00;

                    }
                }else{
                    $odata['totalOrderDiscount'] = 0.00;
                }               

                $response= $this->orderData->orderData($odata,$status,$oname);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why someone gave negative on this. +1

Comment: Do you want to get it after place order?

Comment: yes, after place order

Comment: there is an event `sales_order_place_after` here you can get order date and other stuff, but before that order is not placed and you can not get order date before placing order

Comment: Not able to get order purchase date with this $order->getCreatedAt();

Comment: Can you suggest?

Comment: What event did you use to get order data?

Comment: sales_order_place_after

Comment: I think there are some data that you can't get in order_place_after event, like entity_id, created_at. Because order is placed but not saved in table, and these are only get when order is saved on table.

Comment: Change event to `sales_order_save_after` it will work for you

Comment: The only issue that you would face is, this even will also fire when you save order on backend

Comment: I update my question with code. Please check

Comment: your code is fine, you need to change event from `sales_order_place_after` to `sales_order_save_after`

Comment: Thank you, I get the purchase date. Can you tell me how to get purchase from(e.g store name)?

Comment: Let me add whole thing in answer, along with purchase from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine you just have to change event

from `sales_order_place_after` to `sales_order_save_after`

after that you can get create at by this:

```
$order->getCreatedAt();
```

and Purchased From with this:

```
$order->getStoreName();
```

**Note: The only issue that you would face is, this even will also fire when you save order on backend**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code Spinnet:

```
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
    foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){
       echo '<pre>'; print_r($orderDatamodel1->getData());  
     }
```

**If this works fine, Use this as DI.**

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use sales_order_save_after  event and  get order date.